# How to make an Update subquery inside a CASE-WHEN logic in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, case-when

I want to do an update on my table using the following CASE-WHEN logic:

```
UPDATE    table1
SET   Volume_eur =              
        CASE    


            WHEN TradeCode = 'A' THEN PaymentAmount_field1
            WHEN TradeCode = 'B' THEN PaymentAmount_field2
            WHEN TradeCode = 'C' THEN PaymentAmount_field3

             END                      

                  * CurrencyRate/100

FROM table1
```

But I want to document which logic was used and stamp that on the Statusfield. So basically I want to do an update-statement inside my CASE-WHEN sentence like this: (marked with **bold**)

```
UPDATE    table1
SET              Volume_eur = 

            CASE    


            WHEN TradeCode = 'A' THEN PaymentAmount_field1
```

**UPDATE    table1 SET StatusField = 'Logic1'**

```
            WHEN TradeCode = 'B' THEN PaymentAmount_field2
```

**UPDATE    table1 SET StatusField = 'Logic2'**

```
            WHEN TradeCode = 'C' THEN PaymentAmount_field3
```

**UPDATE    table1 SET StatusField = 'Logic3'**

```
             END                      

                  * CurrencyRate/100

  FROM table1
```

Is that possible, or how should I do it? 
I would like to avoid copying the whole CASE-WHEN logic since it will become harder to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the **case statement** then make 3 seperate queries with different content like this:

```
UPDATE    table1 set Volume_eur=PaymentAmount * CurrencyRate/100_field1 
where TradeCode = 'A';    

UPDATE    table1 set Volume_eur=PaymentAmount * CurrencyRate/100_field2 
where TradeCode = 'B';

UPDATE    table1 set Volume_eur=PaymentAmount * CurrencyRate/100_field3 
where TradeCode = 'C';
```

Hope this is helped you !!

Comment: It's not quite what I was looking for, but I see your point. The problem will be that all the CurrencyRate/100 part will be  replicated 3 times, and that could turn out to be a problem for me, when that part of my code becomes more advanced.